# BeautifulSoup extract

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a "problem" with BeautifulSoup and more especially with re module
Here is the problem:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = """
<div id="my_id">
    <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li class="color12">something</li>
        <li class="color45">something else</li>
    </ul>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(string)
li = soup.find_all('li', {'class': re.compile('color(\d+)')} )
for ele in li:
    print ele['class'] # will print colorXXXX but i would like to know how to get only this XXXX
```

But i would like to extract only the number after color. Is it possible or do I have the obligation to use something like :

```
match = re.search(r'color(\d+)', str(ele['class']))
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to re-apply the regular expression. Just store it in variable and reuse:

```
colorpattern = re.compile(r'color(\d+)')

li = soup.find_all('li', {'class': colorpattern} )
for ele in li:
    print colorpattern.search(ele['class']).group(1)
```

Comment: it doesn't matter in this case but in general use `r''` if there is backslash in the regex

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I should always pay attention to that when c&p-ing OP text.. added.

Comment: could you please explain why store the compiled pattern to a variable will make a difference?

Comment: @Reorx: We save ourselves the hassle of having to specify the pattern twice, and because BS did the tag matching for us first, we know for certain the `.search()` will succeed within the loop. No need to test for `None` anymore there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry I misunderstood the quesion to why the find_all got only one result, so stupid! anyway, thanks for answering :)